# NVIDIA Jetson TX2 not booting

Tags: boot

So I tried to put an image to the jetson bord with

```
dd if=~/disk_image.img of=/dev/sda
```

Unfortunately I got an error message when it was copying the image. I then shutdown the Jetson board.

Since then it does not boot up. When I power on the board it shows nothing on the connected screen.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't resolved this I would go ahead and just re-flash your Jetson with the latest version of Jetpack. This will completely restore your jetson back to a factory state (except it will be running the latest version of Ubuntu L4T of course).

I have done this several times with my TX2 and it always works great. Here are some notes from the last time I had to flash mine:

## JETSON TX2 FLASH JETPACK

#### power off

- hold POWER BTN for 5 seconds

#### connect usb

- micro-B plug recovery port -> host

#### putty serial connection (optional)

- Serial line: COM5
- Speed: 115200

#### enter recovery mode

- hold REC
- press POWER BTN
- press RST
- release REC after 2 seconds

#### verify recovery mode

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0955:7c18 NVidia Corp.
```

#### download and run latest jetpack

https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack

```
$ chmod +x JetPack-L4T-3.3-linux-x64_b39.run
$ ./JetPack-L4T-3.3-linux-x64_b39.run
```